# Strip characters from cURL command output

Tags: bash, curl, command, output, strip

I am looking to take the download progress of a cURL command by taking only the first few characters of its progress bar output. Normally, I would use `${string:position:length}`, but that doesn't seem to work in this situation.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
curl -O https://file.download.link/ > output.txt 2>&1
```

As you can see, I'm redirecting the output of the cURL command to the file output.txt, but let's say I want to only store the first three characters. Using what I just suggested returns a 'bad substitution' error:

```
echo ${curl -O https://file.download.link/:0:3} > output.txt 2>&1
```

so I'm out of my depth here.

If you'd like some more context, I was hoping to then change the command to output to a named pipe, so that it would change the progress of a CocoaDialog progress bar. I'm basically giving a GUI representation of the cURL download progress bar.

I would *really* appreciate any help or advice you could offer, so thank you in advance.

... and my apologies if this is a 'bad' question. I'm fairly new to bash, and scripting in general for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods to get the first three characters of every line/update that curl produces. Note that, after curl prints its header and first output line, each subsequent line/update of output is preceded not by a newline character but by a carriage return, `\r`.  On a terminal, this gives the output its nice update-in-place look.  In our case, we have to add, as shown below, a little bit of special handling to interpret the `\r` correctly.

#### Using tr and grep

```
curl -O https://file.download.link/ 2>&1 |  tr '\r' '\n' | grep -o '^...' >output.txt
```

#### Using awk

```
curl -O https://file.download.link/ 2>&1 | awk -v RS='\r' '{print substr($0,1,3)}' >output.txt
```

#### Sample Output

```
$ curl -O http://www.google.com/index.html 2>&1 | awk -v RS='\r' '{print substr($0,1,3)}'
  %
  0
100
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation, but it doesn't seem to be giving me any output. I copied your code and replaced the link, but when called from terminal nothing is returned (the same from script, empty file is produced).. It looks like it's waiting for stdin to me. Of course, the file still downloads fine. Any ideas?

Comment: OK.  Which version did you try: grep or awk?  Using google (so we get the same thing), try:  `curl -O http://www.google.com/index.html 2>&1 |   tr '\r' '\n'` and tell me what you see.

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on here. My problem was that I was trying this with a larger file, so I was confused when the text didn't write in as soon as I began the download. What I really need is for the download progress to be periodically written to the file, rather than all at the end. That way I can constantly update my progress bar.
EDIT: When used from terminal, the values do appear periodically as I would expect.

Comment: @Otuku OK.  That is a problem with buffering.  `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` are standard utilities that attempt to overcome this.  Do you have either installed?  Please have a look [here](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html) and see if any of those solutions fit your circumstances. For example, one of the suggestions there is to use `gawk` in place of `awk`.

Comment: @Otuku More examples of fixing buffering problems are [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

Comment: Doesn't look like I have any of the commands mentioned (except for awk, grep and sed) installed (command not found), and the ones I do have aren't working. The link I'm trying to download from is here: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/llmqn4pvzh01rde/1.7.10.zip), in case you'd like to tamper around with the downloading yourself.

Comment: @Otuku This prints out progress nicely for me: `unbuffer curl -O 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/llmqn4pvzh01rde/1.7.10.zip' | gawk -v RS='\r' '{print substr($0,1,3)}'`.  On a debian-like system, `unbuffer` can be installed via `apt-get install expect-dev`.

Comment: Apparently  I don't have `apt-get` either, and it's not under the `apt` command according to `man -k`. I don't dkpg either, and I can't seem to find any other options on the web. I'm running OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: @Otuku `apt-get` is for Debian-like systems (Debian, Ubuntu,...) and OSX is _not_ Debian-like.   [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/53604) claims to show how to conquer the buffering problem on OSX using `script -q /dev/null command`.  (I don't have access to OSX so I can't test it.)  Each command whose output goes to a pipe will need to be unbuffered this way.

Comment: I did see that before, but I assumed it didn't apply to me considering I don't have a 'print_progress' function, that's done by cURL its self. I tried like this:
'script -q /dev/null curl -O https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sqs2irwk7y29y8j/libraries.zip 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -o '^...' > output.txt'
But that seems to bring back the buffering problem, and also makes this file rather than what I was expecting: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v63x8ztr2q8eiui/output.txt?dl=0

The awk method echoes "scr" and makes a file with an invalid file/directory err when used in conjunction with 'script -q'.

Comment: @John1024, I wouldn't describe `unbuffer` as a "standard utility". It's part of the `expect` package; expect isn't POSIX-standardized, and is pretty hefty -- you won't find it on any platform that doesn't ship a full TCL interpreter.